# Questions about the endpoints_listener.ora

Tags: oracle, listener

1. How to understand the backward compatibility with pre-11.2 databases of the `endpoints_listener.ora` in depth?
2. Why would manually editing the listener.ora not lead to automatically updating its corresponding `endpoints_listener.ora`？

Updated with the following:

1. Oracle offical document(Doc ID 1070607.1) does decsribe the endpoints_listener backward compatibility。。。！

   "Endpoints_listener.ora file is there for backward compatibility with pre-11.2 databases."
2. Just want to know the hidden principle about updating the endpoints_listener.ora via some program, i.e. netca ！

https://mathijsbruggink.com/2013/07/19/endpoints_listener-ora-not-updated-when-altering-listener-ora-by-hand/

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. We do strive to answer as many questions as possible, but this depends on a lot of factors. Currently, your question is a bit hard to grasp/understand. (Q1) What do you mean with backward compatibility? (Q2) Possibly, because you need to use the `SVCTL` command utility to configure RAC nodes and the underlying `endpoints_listener.ora` file. Hit the [edit] button and try to add more details to your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone could update my question ？